# Spring boot, with grpc: How to do request validation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data, grpc-java

With spring web MVC, the documentation is clear on how to do request validation.

But couldn't find any way to validate gRPC request, or to manually execute the validation on it.

So is there any library, way, or documentation that I can use or follow to make gRPC request validation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [protoc-gen-validate](https://github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate). It's the closest there is for protobuf, but still in alpha.